# Can we create self variable from another variable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create dynamic self variable.

I am having the below code

```
import json
class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        with open("file") as f:
            data = json.load(f)
        fields = data["messages"] # it returns a string as "val1|val2|val3|val4"
        new_fields = fields.split("|")
        ##I want to create self variables as self.val1 = <some value>, self.val2 = <some_value>, self.val3 = <some_value>, self.val4 = <some_value>
        a = "version"
        self.a = 10 ### I want to retreive self.version since a is version
        print ("***************", self.version)

    def pri(self):
        print("*************", self.version)
```

I am not getting the output. I want output as 10. There are lots of variables which I want to create dynamically.

I want to create dynamic self variable. I will read the variable from another file and create a class variable. Is it possible in python?

Those giving negative comments, please help me in writing this better. Please add a comment why you feel you voted it down

Comment: what is your expected output / result. What do you mean by dynamic self variable? You should describe a little more specific what you want to get help here. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Expected output is 10

Comment: @FlorianH: Edited code. See if you can understand this and help me

Comment: How is json relevant to the question?

Comment: I think what the OP wants is to pass the name of a variable as a string parameter to an instance method, and presumably its value, and the code creates an instance variable with that name and with that value.

Comment: @cdarke: It is the code snippet I have provided. Is there any difficulty in understanding code ? Please help me in making this better. I am reading values from another file

Comment: Also you need to make `ABC` inherit from `object`

Comment: @barny - only in the old Python 2

Comment: There are so many unknowns in this question...

Comment: @barny : Can you give me code snippet

Comment: **No**. Don't do this. Use a *container* like a `list` or a `dict`

Comment: @Nitesh no you should write your own code

Comment: @barny: I did not get your explanation. That is the reason asked for code snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following using `setattr`,

```
class ABC:
    def __init__(self, args, val):
        a = args
        self.a = val ### I want to retreive self.version since a is version
        setattr(self, a, self.a)
        print ("***************", self.version)

    def pri(self):
        print("*************", self.version)

a = ABC("version", 10)
a.pri()

('***************', 10)
('*************', 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


class ABC:
    def __init__(self):
        self.version = 10 ### I want to retreive self.version since a is version


    def pri(self):
        print("*************", self.version)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = ABC()
    o.pri()
```

output:

```
************* 10
```

you probably want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class ABC:
    def __init__(self, version):
        self.version = version ### I want to retreive self.version since a is version


    def pri(self):
        print("*************", self.version)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    o = ABC(10)
    o.pri()
```

same output than previous example

Comment: There are n number of variables i want to create

Comment: you can pass a dict instead of a single variable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use a dictionary.  For example:

```
class Myclass: 
    def __init__(self):

        self.__fields = {}
        self.__fields["version"] = 10

        ### I want to retreive self.version since a is version
        a = "version"
        self.__fields[a] = 10
        print ("***************", self.__fields["version"])

    def pri(self):
        print ("***************", self.__fields["version"])

obj = Myclass()
obj.pri()
```

I omitted the json code since I don't have your original file to reproduce and test.

EDIT:
To use alternative names you can use `property` (getter is shown here):

```
class Myclass: 
    ...

    def pri(self):
        print ("***************", self.val1)

    @property
    def val1(self):
        return self.__fields["version"]

obj = Myclass()
print(obj.val1)
```

Comment: You are right. But old code in my framework is getting values as self.val1, self.val2. If i use dict or list, I have to change all of the old libraries. That is the reason I don't want to use dict or list. Your understanding is correct. This is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: OK, maybe you need to use properties.

Answer (score -2):

You created a class but didn't instantiate it also there is no call for main
add this in your code

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    abc=ABC()
    abc.init()
    abc.pri()
```